# 404 Not Found Error comes up while sending post AJAX request to Laravel Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to send dta from view to Laravel Controller via ajax post call. and it giving me error 404 not found i have checked things many but i cant find mistake.

```
class AttemptController extends Controller {
     public function postSavegame(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->all();
        print_r($data);
        //insert data to db
        $id = $this->model->insertRow($data, $request->input($data));

        // Insert logs into database
        if ($id != '') {
             \SiteHelpers::auditTrail($request, 'New Data with ID ' . $id . ' Has been Inserted !');
            echo('Done');
        } 
    }
}
```

here is the AJax from view:

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "{{ URL::to('Attempt/savegame') }}",
            data: {
                quiz_id: localStorage.quiz_id,
                user_id: "{{Session::get('uid')}}",
                total_score: localStorage.achivePoints, // a JSON object to send back
                success: function (response) { // What to do if we succeed
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            },
        });
```

and this is my route entry

```
Route::post("gamesave", "AttemptController@gamesave");
```

Comment: You have `savegame` in your ajax, and `gameSave` in your route.

Comment: it dose's effects

Comment: No, what I mean, is that in your ajax call, you have part of the URL as `savegame`, but the route has `gamesave`. It's not finding the route because those aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your router you should have like-

```
// you should write exactly the same name defined in controller
Route::post("/gameSave", "AttemptController@postSavegame");
```

and in ajax -

```
// you have to use exaclty same url specified in router  
url :   "{{ URL::to('/gameSave') }}",
```

Comment: Please let me know ... whether it works for you or not.. if helpful please accept as correct answer and upvote